# visual glitch when presenting dialog any time after the first attempt

Tags: vaadin

I am having a problem with a subclass of CustomComponent in Vaadin 6 application.
When I launch dialog for the first time, everything is drawn as it should be.

[image: Panel presented for the first as expected]

But when I perform some actions and close dialog afterwards and open a **new** instance of this dialog, I get a visual glitch like this (an extra field to the right is shown as well even though during init phase it is not added to the panel)
[image]

Is it possible to remove this UI caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is caching, I don't have seen this in vaadin in the years I have used it.

I think you are adding the double components each time you open the form.
And if you don't create a new instance of the form, but reuse a already allocated instance, it doubles your component.

Please double-tripple-check your form code.

If you don't find the issue, please post the relevant parts of the form code here.

Comment: Interesting. I also thought about it. At the moment I am creating my components with help of Spring CDI (@Component(ViewBeanName.USER_FILTER_DIALOG)
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) and @Autowired). I will try to create components "manually" and will see what happens next.

Comment: You are right. The bean itself has been created and used ever since. When I forced bean's creation again by (UserFilterDialog) applicationContext.getBean(ViewBeanName.USER_FILTER_DIALOG), everything went fine.